# AWS EC2 ELB Docker Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running into issues running docker-compose because an elastic load balancer. Setup is ELB does 443 -> TCP 80 and docker does `0.0.0.0:80->4444/tcp`

However the server doesn't seem to be hit and I get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Trying to verify if this is a docker setup issue. `Docker version 1.12.6` and `docker-compose version 1.12.0`

is it normal for the bridge config to not have a `Gateway` defined?

````
```
[root@loom-server1 ec2-user]# docker network inspect 8f1b234bfb0b
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "8f1b234bfb0b6c41962265299871cd8053757ec145f8e3f6b63960b71ceb3690",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "bbd2b84545a0e3519e37fb4015eea45637b75ccaa1dd362aff68ff41f3118055": {
                "Name": "dockercompose_loom_1",
                "EndpointID": "b7da2d31ff2503846d4f621bf355b8522afb8dabd1f02ca638c9ef032afefa76",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```
````

weird part is that it's able to load assets
`ec2-52-53-84-186.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/assets/js/homepage.js`

The link may be up or down as I experiment with instances.

This is all running on opsworks.

Any insight or help would be appreciated.